# Google fonts don't load on RELOAD in mobile

Tags: mobile, fonts, google-api, refresh, reload

We're using Google Fonts on our site. When I delete history, cookies, and data from my mobile browser (Safari on iPhone), the Google Fonts load fine. However, if I reload the page, the Google Fonts don't appear. Instead I get the back-up serif font. This would be fine, except that the back-up is too small and illegible.

It's important to know that this is only a problem on mobile. The site reloads fine on desktop.